# CSS means overwriting but why some css classes override it

Tags: html, css, web-frontend

there is one css that formats the input field globally but when I want to customize it for one specific input field then its not taking effect. I think css is to overwrite the properties but why global css class overrides?

**CSS**

```css
.special{
    margin: 8px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-group date-select-with-expire-option  special">
   <div class="input-group-prepend">
       <span class="input-group-text"> 
           <i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i>
       </span>
   </div>
   <input type="text" class="form-control date-input" name="SelectedDate" placeholder="Select date" />
</div>
```

Here is my code example on [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Raakh5/pvf4y235/19/)

Comment: It isn't overriding, if you change the margin in `.special` to `80px` as opposed to `8px` you can clearly see the difference. The `.special` is being used not the `input` selector.

Comment: @JayHales no: here both rules would apply: 8px vertical margin would be set to the input and 80px to the div. You can allways check the browser code inspector to see what is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because for the `input` in the linked fiddle the `.special` is **inherited** style while `input[type=text]` is **directly targeted** and as noted [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity):

> Styles for a directly targeted element will always take precedence over inherited styles, regardless of the **specificity** of the inherited rule.

Read about the specificity [here](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#specificity-rules): in CSS, later rule overwrites the earlier only on the same specificity level (with the exception of inheritance quoted above), otherwise greater specificity wins, regardless of the order.